# Solid background generator will not display any background

Tags: javascript, css

complete newbie here.
I'm trying to create a background generator that isn't the linear gradient type version and when I access the color wheel, the background doesn't change. Here's the code for it.

```js
var css = document.querySelector("h3");
var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
var body = document.getElementById("gradient");

function setGradient() {
    body.style.background = "#"+ color1.value;

    css.textContent = body.style.background + ";";
}

color1.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
```

```html
<body id="gradient">
    <h1>Background Generator</h1>
    <input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#00ff00">
    <h2>Current CSS Background</h2>
    <h3></h3>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it, what needed to be removed was the `"#"` before `color1.value` when you try to assign the body's background color. The values from `color1.value` are already Hex color codes so they have the starting hash. Try this out.

```js
var css = document.querySelector("h3");
var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
var body = document.getElementById("gradient");
const currentColor = document.querySelector(".current");

function setGradient() {
    body.style.background = color1.value;
    css.textContent = body.style.background + ";";
}

color1.addEventListener("input", setGradient);
```

```html
<body id="gradient">
    <h1>Background Generator</h1>
    <input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#00ff00">
    <h2>Current CSS Background</h2>
    <h3></h3>
</body>
```

Comment: Aw man, I got a long way to go.. thank you so much for finding a solution for my naive and dumb self :( I appreciate it!!!!

Comment: @JRP Your welcome! Don't beat yourself up. You created something really cool so keep up the good work!